# Is it possible to make a dictionary with lists as values from a list of dictionaries, in a one line comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

If I have list of dicts A:

```
A = [{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

can I make the following dict:

```
B = {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4]}
```

using only dict/list comprehension?

bonus: can I also account for varied keys in A e.g:

```
A = [{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}]
B = {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [None, 5]}
```

I have managed to do this with a for loops and if statements, was hoping for something that processes faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
A = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5}]

out = {k: [d.get(k) for d in A] for k in set(k for d in A for k in d)}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [None, 5]}
```

Comment: wow thanks, its going to take me a while to get my head around that one. I guess a follow up question is, would you implement it this way if your primary goal was to make the code as fast as possible?